# rosserial error on Raspbian

Tags: ros, rosserial, ros-groovy, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use rosserial on Raspbian using ROS Groovy.  I am trying to run `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0` but I get this error `[ERROR] [WallTime: 1363226987.379253] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125`.  I compile the code on an Ubuntu 12.04 laptop and can get it to run on the Ubuntu machine but as soon as I plug it into the Raspberry Pi, I get that error.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58070/rosserial-error-on-raspbian/) by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2549 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I upgrade the rosserial on the Raspi to the latest one and it worked locally on the Raspi but the Master could not echo the topic.  Will the sudo apt-get ros-groovy-rosserial be updated to the latest version?

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-03-19**:
Debians only sync to public every so often. The updated rosserial is currently in shadow-fixed, so it will be in the next public sync, but I don't know when that will occur.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-19**:
Is there a major difference between the current stable source version and one available from public sync?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-03-26**:
Quite a bit. Originally, 0.2.0 got released by the groovy migration team as 0.3.0 wouldn't build. Recently we've released 0.4.x (currently 0.4.4 I believe). The 0.4.0 series has a number of fixes and improvements. It should be in public debians as of this last sync.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-26**:
I installed the latest from source and it works fine.  Thanks. The one from the public debians gave me problems.  Any updates on rosserial_xbee?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-03-26**:
rosserial_xbee has not been maintained for quite some time, as such it has been moved into the rosserial_experimental stack.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-26**:
Is there a reason why it is not maintained?  Will the kforge version work on groovy using rosmake?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-03-26**:
Nobody has stepped forward to maintain it. It may work via rosmake, not entirely sure. We did move it to https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial-experimental so that it would not be lost if Kforge eventually dies.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-26**:
Is the package just lacking catkinization? Can you recommend a solution for wireless communicating to an Arduino?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-03-26**:
Certainly it is lacking catkinization, beyond that I have no idea what else may or may not be working inside, especially given the recent refactoring of rosserial to handle numerous changes/deprecations in roslib.

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-03-31**:
Hi I am currently getting this error message when running on an Arduino Mega via a PC running Ubuntu 12.04.

I have install rosserial via "sudo apt-get ros-groovy-rosserial" but still get this error. Not sure how to update the version or fix this off your comments here :-( what did you do to fix?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-31**:
Install from source to fix it.  Here is the link https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-03-31**:
ok cool, following the install from source guide on the rosserial page. When running "catkin_make install" I get an error saying "Invoking "make" failed"

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-31**:
Apply this fix: https://github.com/edsfocci/rosserial/commit/56857cb97c010e353d304832acb1ceec22c0d933

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-04-01**:
That worked perfectly, thank you!

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-04-01**:
Glad to hear.